# Understanding when to use : , @ and without any in vue

Tags: vue.js

I have been going through an already existing code and trying to understand different parameters passed inside a tag.

```
<some-element 
    placeholder ="show first name"
    :someElement = "true"
    @error = "showErrorAlert"
>
```

so what exactly is the difference between these three parameters passed and when to pass them.

I am very new to vue so I am struggling a bit.

If any one needs any further information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

to communicate data between components in vuejs we have two concept: `props` and `events`.

[vue props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

[vue custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

read the two links above to learn about them from vue documentation but in short say we have a component structure like this:

```
<parent-component>
---- | <child-component>
```

data flow from parent to child is done with the help of `props`. that is when you're defining `child-component` you can set in its vue instance object that this component can accept some prop like this.

```
props: {
  text: { type: String },
  value: { type: Boolean },
}
```

then when you use this component in the parent one you can pass the defined props to the component like this:

```
<child-component text="some text" :value="false" />
```

notice the `:` notation is just a shorthand for `v-bind:value="false"`, if you don't use this binding the `false` will be sent to the child component as a `string`. for any other value type you should use binding.

please read the docs to learn more about binding in vue

[attribute binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

[v-bind shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand)

now, the data flow from child to parent is done via `events` so in your child component you can `emit` an event for the parent one to listen to like this:

```
this.$emit('event-name', payload)
```

then in the parent component where you used child component you can listen to this event like this

```
<child-component @event-name="doSomethingFun($event)" />
```

where `doSomethingFun()` is a method in parent component and we are passing the payload sent from child component to this method with `$event`

notice `@` notation is shorthand for `v-on` like `v-on:event-name="doSomethingFun($event)"`

Answer (score 0):

`:` is shorthand for `v-bind:` and this is used for dynamic rendering for the attributes such as src, href etc.

`@` is shorthand for `v-on:click` which is event handler for function calls.

You can read more [Event handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) [shorthand syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand)